# Anyone knows how to change the date format in a 2sxc app (in the backend)

Tags: dotnetnuke, user-experience, 2sxc

By default the date format in the 2sxc backend is MM/dd/yyyy.
However we would like to use our own format.
Does anyone know if this is possible at all?
[image: screenshot of 2sxc edit form]

Comment: I believe it uses the date format of the current browser culture settings?

Comment: Just checked, but it doesn't. It keeps using american style dates.

Comment: so just to be clear, this is not backend-format, but front-end. internally dates are stored as date objects (without a format). So you are probably missing a locale which should be used in the date picker. I believe you've opened an issue for this - let's continue the conversation there.

Comment: Yes I see you guys responded on the ticket so let's close this...